# Date say that we are 1st april and forget 29th,30th,31st

Tags: php, date

I'm working with some dates in PHP, and the problem is that today, php return me that we are the 1st of April.
I don't really know why

Tried to change the code to get the date.

```
$actArray= array();
for($i=0;$i<30;$i++){
    $date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $date->modify("-".$i." days");
    $date->modify("-1 months");
    $actArray[date("Y-m-d",time()-60*60*24*$i)]=array("display"=>$date->format("Y, m, d"),"MaxPlayers"=>0,"PlayersOn"=>0,"Register"=>0);
}
```

Alerdy tried

```
for($i=0;$i<30;$i++){
    $date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d",time()-60*60*24*$i));
    $date->sub(new DateInterval("P1M"));
    $actArray[date("Y-m-d",time()-60*60*24*$i)]=array("display"=>$date->format("Y, m, d"),"MaxPlayers"=>0,"PlayersOn"=>0,"Register"=>0);
}
```

Same result

It seem that he skip 3 days.

Output : 2019, 03, 01 2019, 02, 28 2019, 02, 27 2019, 02, 26 2019, 02, 25 2019.....2019, 02, 28

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every month has 30 days, some have even less.

Not all days have 24 hours.

DateTime / strtotime has so many options, you'll never need to do fancy time calculations yourself.

Consider this code:

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
echo $today->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
$today->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 days'));
echo $today->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;

$today = new DateTime('today');
echo $today->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
$today->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month'));
echo $today->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
2019-03-29
2019-02-27
2019-03-29
2019-03-01
```

You see, there is a difference between "30 days" and "1 month"...

Another example:

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
echo $today->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++) {
    $today->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 days'));
    echo $today->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}

2019-03-29
2019-03-30
2019-03-31
2019-04-01
2019-04-02
2019-04-03
```

Comment: Yep, i see, thanks for your help first :D And just i don't really understand why my code is working all the year expect in March to April. As i said, i do graphs with 30 days. I don't take a month, but the graph is adapted to. The problem is really March to April. (And for the fancy time it's my colleague, personally i use modify)

Comment: It is not April yet (and your example doesn't show Aprils dates). Your date sequence in the initial post looks correct (eg. Feb. 28th, then Mar. 1st). 

What is the timezone? And why do you think that 3 days were skipped? I can't see that...

Comment: "Europe/Paris" : I think that cause it's happen only on April, it seem 1 year that happen between Apr/March, it works every other months that's why.

Comment: Please explain again where you see 3 skipped days?

Comment: I put you screen of the graph, if you want i can put you the array as row

Comment: STOP calculating times manually! This year summertime change will be on march 31, which means this day will NOT have 24 hours!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use date() function? It returns the local time/date.

you can get today's date:

```
echo date("Y, M, d");
```

for more details: [date function php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

https://www.guru99.com/php-date-functions.html good reference

Comment: I alerdy tried `$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));` It don't change something, and as you see, i use in object and not only the function cause i need 30 days

Comment: DateTime accepts a string of this format ("y-m-d"), but date returns the string in this format ("y,m,d"), you can replace the comma using replace function:

`$date = date("Y,m,d");
$output = str_replace(',', '-', $date);
echo $output;

$date = new DateTime($output);`

Comment: Also note that not all months have only 30 days 

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting, it seem to work only for once and stop working. But i think that can be a possible solution. :D (And for the 30days, i select 30 values in db :P) but it doesn't matter here with the pb of why it skip 3 days "=" only on march since 1 year